# why is Prettier extension showing Error while working

Tags: prettier

I opened a Diamond Standard file directory and then noticed my prettier extension was highlighted red, when I clicked on the extension, I got the below response:

```
["INFO" - 9:35:17 AM] Extension Name: esbenp.prettier-vscode.
["INFO" - 9:35:18 AM] Extension Version: 9.9.0.
["INFO" - 9:37:52 AM] Attempted to determine module path from /home/page/Desktop/DAO WEB3bridge/Web3Bridge-DAO
["ERROR" - 9:37:52 AM] Failed to load module. If you have prettier or plugins referenced in package.json, ensure you have run `npm install`
["ERROR" - 9:37:52 AM] Cannot find module 'prettier' from '/home/page/Desktop/DAO WEB3bridge/Web3Bridge-DAO'
Error: Cannot find module 'prettier' from '/home/page/Desktop/DAO WEB3bridge/Web3Bridge-DAO'
    at e.exports [as sync] (/home/page/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.9.0/dist/extension.js:1:37102)
    at t.ModuleResolver.findPkg (/home/page/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.9.0/dist/extension.js:1:7353)
    at t.ModuleResolver.getPrettierInstance (/home/page/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.9.0/dist/extension.js:1:3313)
    at handleActiveTextEditorChanged (/home/page/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.9.0/dist/extension.js:1:9679)
    at h.invoke (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:145)
    at v.deliver (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:2266)
    at g.fire (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:1844)
    at /snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:94:178868
    at h.invoke (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:145)
    at v.deliver (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:2266)
    at g.fire (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:1844)
    at v.acceptDocumentsAndEditorsDelta (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:94:16031)
    at v.$acceptDocumentsAndEditorsDelta (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:94:14120)
    at l._doInvokeHandler (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:102:13680)
    at l._invokeHandler (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:102:13362)
    at l._receiveRequest (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:102:12132)
    at l._receiveOneMessage (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:102:10834)
    at /snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:102:8941
    at h.invoke (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:145)
    at v.deliver (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:2266)
    at g.fire (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:1844)
    at r.fire (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:70:16515)
    at /snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:118:17104
    at h.invoke (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:145)
    at v.deliver (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:2266)
    at g.fire (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:1844)
    at r.fire (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:70:16515)
    at o._receiveMessage (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:70:21327)
    at /snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:70:18770
    at h.invoke (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:145)
    at v.deliver (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:2266)
    at g.fire (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:61:1844)
    at g.acceptChunk (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:70:13346)
    at /snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:70:12476
    at Socket.i (/snap/code/112/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:70:24594)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

I checked google but nothing reasonable popped up...If anyone has had a similar experience, I will like to know what to do ...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem.And my last solution is to downgrade the version of Prettier Extension to `9.18.0`.And it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).